# Contraception in hinduism?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, sex, dharmasutra

I'm fully aware hinduism prohibits barrier method(condoms, etc.) but what is its stance on other methods like sterilization or hormonal stuff?

Comment: Are you referring to vasectomy or tubectomy?

Comment: Yes, and pills ig. @Bingming

Comment: Hmm, these (vasectomy, tubectomy, and birth control pills) are kinda recent developments, so smṛtis don’t comment upon them afaik. Based on what I know, consumption of birth control pill is most likely not a pāpa, such oral contraceptive methods (powders, etc. made of herbs to avoid pregnancy after intercourse) are mentioned in later Āyurveda śāstras (not by Caraka & Suśruta), and not opposed in smṛtis.